# IntelliJ Typescript Reference Paths Aren't Relative

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, typescript, gulp, webstorm

I'm using IntelliJ as my IDE but I want to use `gulp-typescript` to compile my typescript. The issue is, IntelliJ is not treating my reference paths relatively but from my app root, meaning I can get references to work for either IntelliJ or the Compiler but not both.

[image]

This file is in `app/components/my-module/my-module.module.js` where the definition is in `app/definitions/tsd.d.ts`. How do I resolve this to where everyone is happy?

Comment: I resolved it by switching to Atom and/or VSCode. IntelliJ's handling for TS is pretty lousy, despite their claims to support it.

Comment: Unfortunately our entire team is using IntelliJ. I'm hoping there is an integrated solution.

Comment: I am using IntelliJ 13 instead of 14. Maybe updating will reveal more options.

Comment: Yes. It was IntelliJ 13 that was the problem. Looks like they solved it in 14.

Answer (score 0):

I was using IntelliJ 13. After upgrading to IntelliJ 14 references were treated as relative paths.